# feedback on mux in verilog

Tags: verilog, feedback, mux

I am preforming a feedback mux calculation using verilog. But however the system does not response (giving X) to one of input which is B (the input controlled by the mux). Can helping me pointing out where is the error and how to fix it.

Here are the codes:

```
module test(input sel,input [3:0]a,b,output [3:0]o);
localparam in_0 = 4'd0;
wire [3:0]w1;

assign w1 = a + b;
assign o = w1 | 4'd0;
assign b = (sel)?w1:in_0;

endmodule
```

Here are the testbench:

```
module test_tb();

reg sel;
reg [3:0] a,b;
wire [3:0]o;

test U1(.sel(sel),.a(a),.b(b),.o(o));

initial begin
sel <= 1'b0;
a <= 4'd2;
#2;
sel <= 1'b1;
#2;
a <= 4'd1;
#2;
sel <= 1'b0;
a <= 4'd4;
#2;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: w1 is only 1 bit wide, it should be 4.

Comment: @Morgan, Sorry about that, but still the same result after w1 been change to 4 bit wide.

Comment: b is an input, but again you are trying to write (assign b = (sel)?w1:in_0;)

Comment: @Emman, i wan the b is equal to 0 when the sel is 0 and b is the output of the previous o when sel is 1.

Comment: @Jack93 Emmans point was that you can not overdrive inputs like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the testbench (the initialization) it seems that `b` is not an `input` (it's just the output of multiplexer)

I think you want to implement the following circuit :

[image]

But to avoid creating loops (when sel=1), you should add a `clk` port to your design in order to control the operation :

```
module test(
    input  clk,
    input  sel,
    input  [3:0] a,
    output [3:0] o
);

    wire [3:0] b;
    reg  [3:0] w1;

    assign o = w1;
    assign b = (sel)?w1:4'd0;

    always @(posedge clk)
        w1 <= a + b;

endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your method just work well, but however i notice that there are delay in the output . Any method to overcome it?

Comment: Can you explain more about the delay? The output is updated on each clock rising edge. It's necessary to change the inputs and wait until clock rising edge to see the correct result, otherwise (without clock) loops is created.

Comment: my mux fail to run in this case. Is this due to the clocking issue?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003167/feedback-on-mux-fail-to-run-in-verilog

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example :

```
module test(
  input sel,
  input [3:0] a,
  input [3:0] b,
  output [3:0]o
);
localparam in_0 = 4'd0;
wire [3:0]w1;

assign w1 = a + b;
assign o = w1 | 4'd0;
assign b = (sel)? w1 : in_0;
```

Note that with `sel==1` you have `w1 = a+b`, and `b =w1`which is w1= a+w1; as a combinatorial loop. this will not work. If there was a flip-flop inside to break the loop then it would behave like an accumulator.

Aa noted by [Emman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970427/emman) that b is an input and therefore the value can not be overriden.

This line `assign b = (sel)? w1 : in_0;` is not valid. Note that it never actually uses the input value as this completely overrides it in all situations.

Comment: Adding to it when you make reg [3:0] b at your testbench to wire [3:0] b you will find an infinite loop (modelsim errors as :Iteration limit reached at time 2 ns.) refer : http://www.edaplayground.com/x/534